# Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnind4jcuda in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, hpc, dl4j

I am working with DeepLearning4j library. I am running everything on HPC and I generate a jar file to submit with spark-submit. I am using the version M1.1. Everything was fine with the CPU but when I switched to GPU, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.nd4j.jita.concurrency.CudaAffinityManager.getNumberOfDevices(CudaAffinityManager.java:136)
        at org.nd4j.jita.constant.ConstantProtector.purgeProtector(ConstantProtector.java:60)
        at org.nd4j.jita.constant.ConstantProtector.<init>(ConstantProtector.java:53)
        at org.nd4j.jita.constant.ConstantProtector.<clinit>(ConstantProtector.java:41)
        at org.nd4j.jita.constant.ProtectedCudaConstantHandler.<clinit>(ProtectedCudaConstantHandler.java:69)
        at org.nd4j.jita.constant.CudaConstantHandler.<clinit>(CudaConstantHandler.java:38)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.nd4j.common.config.ND4JClassLoading.loadClassByName(ND4JClassLoading.java:62)
        at org.nd4j.common.config.ND4JClassLoading.loadClassByName(ND4JClassLoading.java:56)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initWithBackend(Nd4j.java:5152)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:5093)
        at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.<clinit>(Nd4j.java:270)
        at org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader.transformImage(NativeImageLoader.java:670)
        at org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader.asMatrix(NativeImageLoader.java:593)
        at org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader.asMatrix(NativeImageLoader.java:281)
        at org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader.asMatrix(NativeImageLoader.java:256)
        at org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader.asMatrix(NativeImageLoader.java:250)
        at org.datavec.image.recordreader.BaseImageRecordReader.next(BaseImageRecordReader.java:247)
        at org.datavec.image.recordreader.BaseImageRecordReader.nextRecord(BaseImageRecordReader.java:511)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.initializeUnderlying(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:194)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:341)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:421)
        at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:53)
        at com.examples.DeepLearningOnSpark.imageNet_image.streaming.NetworkRetrainingMain.entryPoint(NetworkRetrainingMain.java:55)
        at com.examples.DeepLearningOnSpark.imageNet_image.streaming.NetworkRetrainingMain.main(NetworkRetrainingMain.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ND4J is probably missing dependencies. For more information, please refer to: https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/nd4j/backend
        at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.<init>(NativeOpsHolder.java:116)
        at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.<clinit>(NativeOpsHolder.java:37)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnind4jcuda in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1718)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1328)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1132)
        at org.nd4j.nativeblas.Nd4jCuda.<clinit>(Nd4jCuda.java:10)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.nd4j.common.config.ND4JClassLoading.loadClassByName(ND4JClassLoading.java:62)
        at org.nd4j.common.config.ND4JClassLoading.loadClassByName(ND4JClassLoading.java:56)
        at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.<init>(NativeOpsHolder.java:88)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/h4/nore667e/.javacpp/cache/deepLearningSimpleOne-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar/org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libjnind4jcuda.so: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/h4/nore667e/.javacpp/cache/deepLearningSimpleOne-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar/org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libnd4jcuda.so)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1668)
        ... 47 more
```

My pom.xml file is:

```
 <properties>
        <dl4j-master.version>1.0.0-M1.1</dl4j-master.version>
        <!-- Change the nd4j.backend property to nd4j-cuda-X-platform to use CUDA GPUs -->
        <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-11.2-platform</nd4j.backend>
     
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <shadedClassifier>bin</shadedClassifier>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.minimum.version>3.3.1</maven.minimum.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.4.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <jcommon.version>1.0.23</jcommon.version>
        <jfreechart.version>1.0.13</jfreechart.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <jcommander.version>1.27</jcommander.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.8</spark.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.1</jackson.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>${shadedClassifier}</shadedClassifierName>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/datanucleus/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--      Added to enable jar creation using mvn command-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>cuda-platform-redist</artifactId>
            <version>11.2-8.1-1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-11.2-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dl4j-spark_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dl4j-spark-parameterserver_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>${jcommander.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for patent classification example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-zoo</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-cuda-11.2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M1.1</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

the modules that I am loading are:

```
 1) modenv/scs5                                                (S)  22) libfabric/1.11.0-GCCcore-10.2.0        43) HDF5/1.10.7-gompic-2020b
  2) Maven/3.6.3                                                     23) PMIx/3.1.5-GCCcore-10.2.0              44) cURL/7.72.0-GCCcore-10.2.0
  3) Java/1.8.0_161-OpenJDK                                          24) OpenMPI/4.0.5-gcccuda-2020b            45) double-conversion/3.1.5-GCCcore-10.2.0
  4) BigDataFrameworkConfigure/0.0.2                                 25) OpenBLAS/0.3.12-GCC-10.2.0             46) flatbuffers/1.12.0-GCCcore-10.2.0
  5) Spark/3.0.1-Hadoop-2.7-Java-1.8-Python-3.7.4-GCCcore-8.3.0      26) gompic/2020b                           47) giflib/5.2.1-GCCcore-10.2.0
  6) GCCcore/10.2.0                                                  27) FFTW/3.3.8-gompic-2020b                48) ICU/67.1-GCCcore-10.2.0
  7) zlib/1.2.11-GCCcore-10.2.0                                      28) ScaLAPACK/2.1.0-gompic-2020b           49) JsonCpp/1.9.4-GCCcore-10.2.0
  8) binutils/2.35-GCCcore-10.2.0                                    29) fosscuda/2020b                         50) NASM/2.15.05-GCCcore-10.2.0
  9) GCC/10.2.0                                                      30) cuDNN/8.0.4.30-CUDA-11.1.1             51) libjpeg-turbo/2.0.5-GCCcore-10.2.0
 10) CUDAcore/11.1.1                                                 31) NCCL/2.8.3-GCCcore-10.2.0-CUDA-11.1.1  52) LMDB/0.9.24-GCCcore-10.2.0
 11) CUDA/11.1.1-GCC-10.2.0                                          32) bzip2/1.0.8-GCCcore-10.2.0             53) nsync/1.24.0-GCCcore-10.2.0
 12) gcccuda/2020b                                                   33) ncurses/6.2-GCCcore-10.2.0             54) PCRE/8.44-GCCcore-10.2.0
 13) numactl/2.0.13-GCCcore-10.2.0                                   34) libreadline/8.0-GCCcore-10.2.0         55) protobuf/3.14.0-GCCcore-10.2.0
 14) XZ/5.2.5-GCCcore-10.2.0                                         35) Tcl/8.6.10-GCCcore-10.2.0              56) protobuf-python/3.14.0-GCCcore-10.2.0
 15) libxml2/2.9.10-GCCcore-10.2.0                                   36) SQLite/3.33.0-GCCcore-10.2.0           57) flatbuffers-python/1.12-GCCcore-10.2.0
 16) libpciaccess/0.16-GCCcore-10.2.0                                37) GMP/6.2.0-GCCcore-10.2.0               58) typing-extensions/3.7.4.3-GCCcore-10.2.0
 17) hwloc/2.2.0-GCCcore-10.2.0                                      38) libffi/3.3-GCCcore-10.2.0              59) libpng/1.6.37-GCCcore-10.2.0
 18) libevent/2.1.12-GCCcore-10.2.0                                  39) Python/3.8.6-GCCcore-10.2.0            60) snappy/1.1.8-GCCcore-10.2.0
 19) Check/0.15.2-GCCcore-10.2.0                                     40) pybind11/2.6.0-GCCcore-10.2.0          61) TensorFlow/2.4.1-fosscuda-2020b
 20) GDRCopy/2.1-GCCcore-10.2.0-CUDA-11.1.1                          41) SciPy-bundle/2020.11-fosscuda-2020b
 21) UCX/1.9.0-GCCcore-10.2.0-CUDA-11.1.1                            42) Szip/2.1.1-GCCcore-10.2.0
```

Anyone has any idea about how to solve this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error while using version 1.0.0-M2 and I made a number of changes, so not sure which fixed it (probably the last one):

- Upgraded IDE IntelliJ to newest version.
- Removed dependencies I was not using (e.g.
  bytedeco,deeplearning4j-zoo,deeplearning4j-nlp)
- Added dependency:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.deeplearning4j/resources/1.0.0-M2

Also try this backend troubleshooting [link](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/multi-project/explanation/configuration/backends).